# OpenVPN Appliance Routing Configuration

Tags: virtual-machine, openvpn

I am trying to set up the OpenVPN VMware ESXi Virtual Appliance. I have downloaded and loaded the VM and gotten it running. I am using the web UI at this point with local authentication. I have created a user and I can log into the server from home using that user. I have assigned a static IP to my user, I can see that IP on my local network adapter, and I can ping the IP address of the server (the IP that is internal to the remote site). The problem is I cannot ping anything else on the network. I am trying to do routing, not NAT, because I need seamless access to the entire network (software development/testing purposes). I don't want anything in the middle mucking with my connection. Below are two screenshots showing my configuration:

VPN Settings

[image: VPN Settings Screen]

User Settings for My User

[image: User Settings Screen]

Any help would be appreciated, I'm pretty new to this stuff and it just doesn't seem like it should be this hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routed network you provided, that is a different network, from the LAN the OpenVPN server is running on right?

Have you added a route for VPN network, on the router that all the clients are on that LAN are using for a default gateway?

Since that network is different, the clients on the LAN must know how to get to it, but I would guess the only route they have is their default gateway.  So they would not know about or how to reach devices on the other side of the VPN.

The important thing to remember about routing is that you must think about both directions of the traffic.  It is easy to add the configuration for getting packets out of a gateway, but overlook the fact, that you have to add configuration to other systems to get the packets too the gateway.

Comment: The IP address of the VM is 10.10.9.9. I'm not sure what you are trying to say (I apologize for my minimal knowledge in this area). Do I need to create a route in the VM, with iptables or something similar?

Comment: Well I can give you a lot more detail, if you spend some time describing your network in more detail.  What other routers exist, what subnets, what IP addresses are assigned to what router interfaces, and what route tables exist.

Comment: We're just a small company with a single subnet (10.10.9.0/24). Our "router" is our firewall (one port is the public IP, the other is 10.10.9.1). The VM is 10.10.9.9 (eth0), there is port forwarding in the firewall to pass the OpenVPN stuff through to the VM. When I log in my VPN assigned IP is 10.10.9.81. Everything resides on the 10.10.9.0/24 subnet.

Comment: So is the OpenVPN in routed or bridged mode?  What IP addresses to the OpenVPN clients get?  If it is in routed mode, you cannot use the same subnet for VPN clients as you have defined on your network.  If it is in routed mode, you need to add a route for the VPN Client subnet, to your Router `10.10.9.1`.

Comment: I'm not sure what mode it's in and I can't find the config files in the virtual appliance (not sure where to look). I changed it so that clients connect to the 10.10.8.0/24 network. I want to bridge it to the 10.10.9.0/24 network. When I log in as a user, I get a 10.10.8.3 address and I can ping 10.10.8.1 and 10.10.9.9, but not 10.10.9.1. If I show the IP routes on the VM, one of the lines says `10.10.9.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.9.9`, which I thought would route between the networks, but it clearly does not.

Comment: So if you changed it to deliver `10.10.8.0/24`, then you need to add a route on your **firewall (10.10.9.1)** for that subnet (10.10.8.0/24) to be routed via to the VPN gateway, which I think you have set to 10.10.9.81.

Comment: Yes, static route in the firewall, everything makes sense now. I very much appreciate your help, thank you.